# How I can install Gimp 2.8 and Gimp 2.9 on the same computer?

Tags: installation, gimp

How I can install Gimp 2.8 and Gimp 2.9 on the same computer and work with both?

Comment: Why do you need to access Gimp 2.9? It is not stable yet and there have not been any releases.

Comment: Thank you by the answer astex my problem is that in gimp 2.8.8 dont works some filter like Resynthesizer I ask before but I can found how I can fix it, so I think to install 2.9 too, but I see that I ll have more troubles, what can I do to fix Resinthesizer??? Thank you

Comment: I asked the question separately before but did not answer adequately and after Takkat put my answer as out of topic, I almost did not ask, I read about Ubuntu, in this problem about resinthesizer don't have reading

Answer (score 0):

You can always just build it from the git repo (git://git.gnome.org/gimp), but if you really want bleeding edge tech all the time rather than something stable and well-documented, you may want to try gentoo or arch.  Either way, you'd want branch master, so:

```
$ git clone git://git.gnome.org/gimp
$ cd gimp
$ git checkout master
```

and follow the instructions in `INSTALL`.  You can just run the binaries from their location in that folder, no need to actually 'install' them to the root bin and lib directories.

If you want two conflicting versions of the same software accessible to aptitude, though, you will have to do some mucking about with package building.

Comment: Thank you by the answer astex my problem is that in gimp 2.8.8 dont works some filter like Resynthesizer I ask before but I can found how I can fix it, so I think to install 2.9 too, but I see that I ll have more troubles, what can I do to fix Resinthesizer??? Thank you

Comment: That's an entirely different question.  If you want an answer, I'd ask it separately.

Comment: I asked the question separately before but did not answer adequately and after Takkat put my answer as out of topic, I almost did not ask, I read about Ubuntu, in this problem about resinthesizer don't have reading